# difference between array and pointer to array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, embedded

Hello Stack overflow community,

Since embedded systems are resources limited, we have to take care of the memory allocation.

So, my question is about this topic (how to save memory?)

Suppose we have this piece of code:

```
extern float externArray[2500];
float testArray[2500];
void fillArray()
{
for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(testArray) / sizeof(float); i++)
  testArray[i] = externArray[i];
}
```

If you're wondering why I'm copying the externArray into the testArray, my application obliges me to do that (because I will pass `externArray` to a function that will modify its values). If you have a better approach to do this, your feedbacks are welcome.

Now I have done this:

```
extern float externArray[2500];
float *testArray;
void fillArray()
{
testArray = (float*) malloc(2500 * sizeof(float));
for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(externArray) / sizeof(float); i++) //here I have to change size of testArray to size of externArray because it's no more longer allocated on the stack
  testArray[i] = externArray[i];
}
```

So I want to know if the second will be more optimized in terms of memory since I'm using a pointer to an array?

Is worth it to use more heap (I mean more pointers to arrays than arrays) ?

Thank you

Comment: The second one is just incorrect, as you allocate 2500 bytes instead of floats.

Comment: A system with 2500 floats doesn't sound resource constrained at all. If you have FPU and that much RAM, you have some upper end MCU. What is the math which you need floating point for? Why do you need 2500 values? None of this makes sense without a specification, what is all this for? And generally, heap allocation is banned in embedded systems. And 2500 floats are 2500 floats no matter how you allocate them.

Comment: @Lundin _**And 2500 floats are 2500 floats no matter how you allocate them**_. This is what I'm looking for, so at the end, if I allocate on the stack or if I use the heap is the same? Naturally, I have to use 45000 values but I have simplified the problem.

Comment: Well actually the presence of a heap means it steals RAM that you could have used for other things. The heap size doesn't magically regrow on a microcontroller. It is set to a fixed value and that is exactly how much RAM it will consume, whether you use it or not. That's why the normal practice is to nuke everything called heap from the linker script.

Comment: stack size may be limited. it depends on the system

Comment: @Lundin, yes I agree with you. so to conclude, with that much of data, the RAM may be corrupted, we can use an external memory in this case to remedy the problem?

Comment: Why would it get corrupted? You either have enough RAM on chip or you don't. This is determined at link-time. The linker script needs to reflect the physical memory available on the MCU.

Comment: @Lundin, I have 512KB of RAM, and I have to use 6 arrays like that one at least

Comment: @bren, I'm with the others about not using the heap. The question is rather, why you need 45000 floats, and why you need 6 such arrays. Maybe you should check how to split into smaller chunks of to work with in the processing chain. And if you really have to copy, than maybe rather use a) a memcpy implmentation or b) the HW if possible (DMA).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dynamic memory allocation will be marginally less efficient in terms of memory usage because of the alignment and heap-management meta-data required to manage allocation and deallocation.

However a more significant issue is that of the non deterministic nature of dynamic allocation.  Allocation will take variable time, and may fail.  Statically allocated arrays take no time and are guaranteed to be available.